# SoapUI. Transferring a random JSON value from array to the next response

Tags: json, soapui

I have to test some REST service via SOAPUI. 
The JSON request response looks something like that

```
    [
      {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Name1",
   },
      {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Name2",
      }
   },
      {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Name3",
         }
         ]
```

I am able to transfer specific `id` of this array to the resource path of the next request /users/{`id`} with Jsonpath expression via Property Transfer.
But how can i select a random `id` from this response and put it in the following request resource path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Groovy Script to randomly generate a number for you based on the size of you array, which in turn can be used with `/users/{id}`

```
//generate a random number using the range of 0 to 3
def randomNumber = Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 4)
log.info randomNumber

//Define json map
def map = [["id":123, "name":"Bob"],
             ["id":321, "name":"John"],
             ["id":333, "name":"Jim"],
             ["id":111, "name":"Sally"]]

//Use random number to select value from list
def selector = map.id[randomNumber]
log.info selector
```

To convert json to a map you can use jsonslurper which you can find more information about [here.](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

Comment: I got the idea, but what if the array doesn't consist of the incrementally increasing numbers, like [123, 45, 23]. I managed to store all my values into one array but have no clue how to extract a random value from it.

Comment: @StanislavSemyonov I have updated my answer, hope this helps

Comment: much obliged, i think that's exactly what i need.

Comment: Youre most welcome, if this answered you question could you please accept it.